# Complex key-value pairs

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in this format

```
"key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3 key2=value6 ...."
```

Keys are alphanumeric with no spaces. Keys can repeat in the string. Values can have any value including spaces, IP addresses etc. Examples of some values are

```
Feb 09 2015 12:28:26 UTC 
20.201.78.57
asdaaq.org
```

I need to able to parse the string and split it into key value pairs and be able to create a Java map>. Can someone suggest an approach to split the string.

I tried regex `^((\b[^\s=]+)=(([^=]|\\=)+))*$` but this is not working for all the cases

Comment: If spaces are allowed in your values there is no way to distinguish between the end of value(n) and the start of key(n+1).

Comment: Can values contain '=' ?

Comment: when I applied it on a string it gave we one match like this. "key1=Feb 09 2015 12:28:26 UTC key2"

Comment: values cannot contain =

Comment: keys can be from a predefined set .

Comment: Will a space always be between each key value?

Comment: cfqueryparam.  your regex worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: don't forget to choose his answer :)

Comment: @dcmovva You mentioned that keys can repeat. That means you will either need to store in a `Map<String,List<String>>` or use a multimap from a third party library.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that the values don't contain `=`, then the task is as simple as:

```
String[] kvPairs = inputString.split("\\s+(?=[A-Za-z0-9]+=)");
```

`(?=[A-Za-z0-9]+=)` is a zero-width assertion that matches the beginning of every key, which is alphanumeric followed by `=`, without any spaces in between. `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace character and treat them as delimiter, so the result won't have any trailing spaces.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: That is certainly an option, probably `\s+(?=...` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it uses lookaheads to stop at before keynames by looking for `=`.

```
([\w\d]+)=([^=]*)(?=\s\w+=|$)
```